# Jones matrices of a mystery device

Tags: optics, polarization

When considering a Jones matrix

$$J=\ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\phi & -\sin\phi \\
\sin\phi & \cos\phi \\ \end{array} \right) $$

I understand that the effect of a device described by this Jones matrix on a linearly polarized light is rotation by angle $\phi$. I identified the corresponding device as a Faraday rotator. 
I found eigenvalues to be

$$\lambda_1=e^{i\phi} \quad \text{and} \quad \lambda_2=e^{-i\phi}$$

and corresponding eigenvectors as

$$\vec{v}_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
i \\ \end{array} \right)
\quad \text{and} \quad 
\vec{v}_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
-i \\ \end{array} \right)\ $$

which have the form of left and right circular polarization states. 
I found Jones matrix in its own diagonal frame to be

$$J'=\ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
e^{i\phi} & 0 \\
0 & e^{-i\phi} \\ \end{array} \right)\ $$

When asked to explain rotational effect of a device described by the first Jones matrix by considering an incident polarised wave to be a superposition of eigenpolarizations, how can I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vectors are $v_1,v_2$ are circularly polarised light, in which the polarisation vector rotates over time. So the matrix $J'$ describes changing the phase relations between $v_1$ and $v_2$. One way to explain the relation would be just to work out the original vector as a superposition of $v_1$ and $v_2$ and then apply $J'$.

Another way to think about it is that $v_1$ and $v_2$ have a polarisation that rotates over time. Linear polarisation in some direction is like the rotation of $v_1$ and $v_2$ cancelling out at a particular angle. And the matrix $J'$ just makes the rotation cancel out at a different angle.

Comment: the quarter wave plate induces a phase change of 90 degrees, which is absent in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Since the matrix shown is a rotation matrix, which rotates an input vector by the angle $\phi $, it should be the Jones matrix for a half wave plate.

Click for a list of devices and their corresponding [Jones matrix representations.](https://spie.org/publications/optipedia-pages/press-content/fg05/fg05_p57-61_jones_matrix_calculus)

The half wave plate "flips" the normally incident linear polarization across the fast axis; this means that if the input polarization makes an angle $\theta $ with the fast axis, the total rotation will be $2\theta $.

A detailed analysis is found at Newport's [polarization page.](http://www.newport.com/Polarization/144921/1033/content.aspx)

Comment: Would you be able to explain this in more detail, please? I did consider a half wave plate at first but because all sources (including the one your provided) describe half wave plate with an additional factor of 1/2, i.e. having Jones matrix

$J=\ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}} & 0 \\
0 & e^{-i\frac{\phi}{2}} \\ \end{array} \right)\ $ 

it didn't seem to be the answer? At the same time, the main use of half-wave plate is to rotate linear polarization by arbitrary angle. It's all a bit confusing.

Comment: @reynevan: I've added to the answer; for the rotation matrix in the OP -- and the one in the reference provided -- the incident plane polarization would be described by the half angle.  Choice of representation doesn't change the physics; in this case it is a simple change of variable.